# How to create a log file when HTTP error response occurs in Angular 10?

Tags: angular, logging, https

I have a simple Angular project where the user can record information about their vehicle such as the identification number, model, etc. I want to create and save text file with message in project folder when 500 error occurs during HTTP event.

Code from the service:

```
export class ErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
      
      constructor(private router: Router) { }
      
      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            return next.handle(req).pipe(retry(environment.REINTENTOS)).pipe(tap(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                if (event.body && event.body.error === true && event.body.errorMessage){
                throw new Error(event.body.errorMessage);
            }
          }
       })).pipe(catchError((err) => {

            const str = err.error.message;

            if (err.error.status === 400){
                this.openSnackBar(str.slice(4, str.length));
            } else if (err.error.status === 500) {
                // create the log with the message and save into the folder "logs"

                this.router.navigate(['/error500']);
            }
            return EMPTY;
       }));
    }  
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "project folder" are you talking about on the user's machine? locally? or on the server?

Comment: @Brandon On the server, the 500 error message makes more sense to the programmer than to the client.

Comment: Something to consider is that if your application is running on one server, that's fine, you can write to the file system, but as soon as you start scaling out, you're going to want to write to a shared file system like Amazon S3 or a separate logging API.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is create a log entry in the project directory on the server that the app is served from.

In that case, my first thought is that you need to make an additional request to an api endpoint that will write the log on the server in your logs folder. The implementation of that will vary depending on your api.

Comment: is any simple way to do that?

Comment: @Daniel it depends on your setup. From the client its as simple as making another request to a url and passing whatever data you want in the log. 

I know its not that helpful, but try googling something like "PHP/Node.js/.NET Logging" and you should find a ton of resources to help with the task. Essentially they all do what you want - write to a file- but they usually make it a cleaner and neater process.